# wordpress category creation automatically from database

Tags: wordpress

I am trying store form data to database and create category dynamically into menu from the stored data in wordpress. could you please help me to add categoryinto my menu automatically.

Comment: please give me your valuable answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Please show us your code and describe where you got stuck.